# xpath working in chrome console but not in protractor script

Tags: google-chrome, xpath, console, protractor

html:

```
<div class="view doc">
  <div class="view-doc-heading-dec mt10 ng-binding" id="docSummaryHeader">   Document Title </div>
  <div class="view-doc-inner mt11 ng-binding" id="docBodyHeader">
</div>
```

I want to retrieve 'Document Title' in above elements with xpath:

```
$x('//*[@id=docSummaryHeader]')[0]
```

works in chrome console

but

```
element(by.xpath('//*[@id=docSummaryHeader]'))
```

in protractor doesn't allow [0]

If I use

```
element(by.xpath('//*[@id=docSummaryHeader]'))
```

it gives multiple elements in current html

Comment: doesn't allow [0]": please expand: does it give an error (then what error?) or something else?

Comment: element(by.xpath('//*[@id=docSummaryHeader]'))  gives error:  Failed: Cannot read property 'findElementOverride' of undefined and $x('//*[@id=docSummaryHeader]') in chrome console gives multiple results in above code as 1. Document title, Title, Body

Comment: That information needs to be in the question: edit to modify

Comment: `//*[@id=docSummaryHeader]` is an invalid XPath - string values need to be quoted: try `//*[@id="docSummaryHeader"]`

Comment: It was my typo error in my question. I am already using it with quote. Please guide me to locate element with element(by.xpath('') with [0]th element in page

Comment: if protractor doesn't allow indexing, try including the index in the XPath (one based) - i.e. `element(by.xpath('(//*[@id=docSummaryHeader])[1]')) `

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Find [all elements](http://angular.github.io/protractor/#/api?view=ElementArrayFinder) and get the desired one by index:

```
element.all(by.xpath('//*[@id="docSummaryHeader"]')).get(0);
```

or:

```
element.all(by.xpath('//*[@id="docSummaryHeader"]')).first();
```

Or, you can use the XPath-indexing (1-based):

```
element(by.xpath('//*[@id="docSummaryHeader"][1]'))
```

Comment: Thanks a lot Mr. Richard, Keith and alecxe for your help. element.all(by.xpath('//*[@id="docSummaryHeader"]')).get(0); Perfectly worked for me...

Answer (score 0):

Actually you don't need xpath here:

```
$$('#docSummaryHeader').first();
```

Consider using CSS selector instead.

Comment: I tried element.all(by.css('[$$('docSummaryHeader')]')).first() however, it fails with error message syntax error with missing ) after argument list. and with   element.all(by.css('[$$(docSummaryHeader)]')).first()  invalid selector. element.all(by.css($$('docSummaryHeader'))). gives maximum call stack size exceeded.

Comment: @SandeepLohar no no no, it much simplier. Just 
`var firstHeader = $$('#docSummaryHeader').first(); `
element.all(by.css ...) not needed.

$$ - is equvalent to element.all(by.css(''));
Check this - http://www.protractortest.org/#/api?view=build$$

Comment: Thanks Xotabu4, Errors fixed with this instruction however it returns reult other than expected value. any ways. xpath is working for now.